# I'm trying to create two unordered list section within an unordered list, so that there are two dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a Unordered List Section with 9 list items.
The fist Li items contains an inner Unordered List.
The fifth Li item also contain an inner Unordered List.
The Li items containing inner UL have "**-**" and "**+**" sign respectively,
when we mouseover these sign they switch and opens the inner UL

Here is the image Showing the UL section that i want to create
[image]

Also there is link for reference to show how the UL section work for better understanding
[Reference Link](https://www.ufv.ca/agriculture/programs/agriculture-technology-diploma/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA15yNBhDTARIsAGnwe0XRWCBpR6HxMZ1fRAqSM8MSh42Y7RUxCkHNtY0OTHOBdDIF57yC5K0aAvIZEALw_wcB)

Can anybody help me with recreating this section using HTML, CSS & JavaScript only

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are not a free code writing service. You are expected to make your best effort to write your code, and share it here to get help. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really good reference to work with. You can see how it works by inspecting the code.

The reference has a `ul` inside a `ul` which is set to `display:none` and changes it to `block` on `hover`.

Here's a simple demo where the list expands on click.

```js
const expand = () => {
    const list = document.querySelector('.innerList');
  list.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.innerList {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>
    one
    <button class='btn' onclick="expand()">+</button>
    <ul class='innerList'>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>a</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Ahsan Khan for your answer to my question, but in the original website the event is mouseover from what i see and the "+" icon changes to "-". So i am little confused with it also the li has a pseudo selector in it